# My mother's Hebrew (Yiddish?) name was Alta Simis. I know Alta means old but I can't find the name Simis. What does it mean?

Tags: hebrew, names

My mother's Hebrew (Yiddish?) name was Alta Simis. I know Alta means old. What does Simis mean and why Jewish practicant people did give this name to girls?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Susan! Thanks for sharing the questions. Not all question are on topic here. If this question is closed as off topic, don't be discouraged. You can try asking it on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam).

Comment: Welcome, Susan! || @mevaqesh [Chat is a privilege that comes with more reputation than Susan currently has](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) (but she can be added by a room owner or moderator). The policy regarding questions about Yiddish names is under discussion, [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4225/5323) -- both of you are invited to chime in if you have opinions to share.

Comment: @Susan Jaffe Albert Simis is possessive, like 'belonging to' or 'from Simi'. It is the same as Rabbi Shmuel Eidels. 'Eidels' means he belongs to Eidel. So in the case of your mother's name it could mean either she was the daughter of Simi or that she was named after her grandmother or great grandmother Simi. Simi is a derivative of Simcha, which means joy.

Comment: Could it have been "Simeh"  סִימָה ? This is a regular Yiddish name